# VB.NET: Load database columns into listview

Tags: listview

I'm trying to load an access database table into a listview's columns. I 've managed to load the first 4 columns of the database but there is a problem with the 5th one.

```
Public Sub DisplayPasswords()
    Passes.Items.Clear()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from passwords", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim myRow As DataRow

    For Each myRow In dt.Rows
        Passes.Items.Add(myRow.Item(1))
        Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
        Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(3))
        Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(4))
        Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(5))
    Next
End Sub
```

The error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Add' can be called with these arguments:

'Public Function Add(item As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem) As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem':
```

This is an image of the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHx1S.png

This is an image of my access database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tuZl.png

This is an image of my listview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVR7y.png

Comment: Well, index probably goes from 0 to 4 , not from 1 to 5 ...

Comment: I know, but I can't think of what the new code will be.

Comment: @user2921419: Well, in that case the new code would use the numbers 0 through 4 instead of 1 through 5.  Barring that, what is the type of `myRow.Item(5)`?  How is it different from the other items before it?  What is the type expected by `.Add()`?

Comment: cfr my answer below... but there might be other problems in your code...

Comment: I've already tried this. The problem is that I get the id column from the access database into the website column of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the problem but I found another way to do the exact same thing.

```
Public Sub DisplayPasswords()
    Main.Passes.Items.Clear()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
     "SELECT * FROM passwords ORDER BY id", _
     con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Do While dr.Read()
        Dim new_item As New  _
 ListViewItem(dr.Item("website").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("username").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("password").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("dates").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("notes").ToString)

        Main.Passes.Items.Add(new_item)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As index goes from 0 to n-1 , where n is the number of items, try this :

```
For Each myRow In dt.Rows
    Passes.Items.Add(myRow.Item(0))
    Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(1))
    Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
    Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(3))
    Passes.Items(Passes.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(4))
Next
```

But I'm not sure to understand what your code is doing, you may encounter other problems...

Comment: I've already tried this. The problem is that I get the id column from the access database into the website column of my application.